# Where can i find my cluster domain in EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy the jpetstore app to EKS and have come across this variable that needs to be filled in. (https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/jpetstore-kubernetes/blob/master/jpetstore/jpetstore.yaml)
[image]

In the documentation it states that i can it using the commands:

```
Edit jpetstore/jpetstore.yaml and jpetstore/jpetstore-mmssearch.yaml and replace all instances of:
<CLUSTER DOMAIN> with your Ingress Subdomain (ibmcloud ks cluster get --cluster CLUSTER_NAME)
```

(https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/jpetstore-kubernetes)

but this is for ibm cloud and i need it for EKS.

Where can i get this `<CLUSTER DOMAIN>` value from?

Comment: The doc looks specific to kubernetes on IBM cloud. Typically the ingress host is the dns hostname users would use to access the service eg www.yourwebsite.com.

Comment: How would I set this up in aws? @jordanm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own name in the ingress spec, example `host: jpetstore.example.com`. You need to [install](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.3/deploy/installation/) AWS LB Controller; which will handle your ingress request and create an ALB based on your ingress spec. You then access like: `curl -H 'HOST: jpetstore.example.com' http://<your new alb endpoint>`

Comment: thanks that helped!